# Trying to fetch a list of values in an array

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to fetch the values within the `fruit` object and within the `options` object. You can see there are a list of items within it `100% Orange Juice, Apple, Pear, Pineapple` and etc. How can loop through a very nested object in order to fetch those values.

I've tried using `foreach` to fetch those items but it seems I'm doing it incorrectly.

```
$fruitsArray = $product->get_attributes('');

foreach ( $fruitsValue as $fruitsArray ) {
    echo $fruitsValue   
}

<?php var_dump($product->get_attributes('')); ?>


array(2) {
  ["size"]=>
  object(WC_Product_Attribute)#2724 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Size"
      ["options"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "400 ml"
        [1]=>
        string(2) "1L"
        [2]=>
        string(2) "2L"
      }
      ["position"]=>
      int(0)
      ["visible"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["variation"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }

["fruit"]=>
  object(WC_Product_Attribute)#2723 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Fruit"
      ["options"]=>
      array(8) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "100% Orange Juice"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "Apple"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "Pear"
        [3]=>
        string(9) "Pineapple"
        [4]=>
        string(12) "Passionfruit"
        [5]=>
        string(15) "Red Dragonfruit"
        [6]=>
        string(13) "Baobab Powder"
        [7]=>
        string(17) "Grapeseed Extract"
      }
      ["position"]=>
      int(1)
      ["visible"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["variation"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you var_dump $product without get_attributes?

Comment: [WC_Product_Attribute](http://hookr.io/classes/wc_product_attribute/) extends [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), so presuming would access like `$fruitsArray['fruit']['options']`, or use the getters (all shown in the docs link)

Comment: @camaulay doing var_dump($product) just fetches all the objects

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's the `options` object which I want to access. You can see there a couple of values contained within the object `Apple, Pear, Pineapple` and etc

Comment: try `print_r($fruitsArray['fruit']->get_options())` :)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone oh, it managed to fetch the values in the array `(
    [0] => 100% Orange Juice
    [1] => Apple
    [2] => Pear
    [3] => Pineapple
    [4] => Passionfruit
    [5] => Red Dragonfruit
    [6] => Baobab Powder
    [7] => Grapeseed Extract
)`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone So I should just loop and fetch those values right?

Comment: you could `echo implode(', ', $fruitsArray['fruit']->get_options())` etc if you want as string or do a loop, it depends what you want to do with them.

Comment: In your foreach, it looks like you have your array and assigned value reversed. Should be foreach($fruitsArray as $fruitsValue)

Comment: I actually wanted to use those values and affix them in a `data-attribute`, `echo str_replace(" ", "-", $fruitsArray['fruit']->get_options());`